# Using PHP Facebook SDK without permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

It's possible to use the new Facebook PHP SDK without asking the user for permissions?

I just want to show some photo albums from a public page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the page is public, and the photo albums are public too, you should be able to get them with the Facebook API.

Have a look at the [Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/albums) for more informations.

Here's a small example of what you could get on the FacebookDevelopers page, for example : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=FacebookDevelopers%2Falbums&version=v2.0